# Покажите красивые вещи на JavaScript html5 CSS3 ?

Tags: css3, javascript, html5

Хочу посмотреть красивые эффекты на JavaScript html5 CSS3, подскажите где можно посмотреть ?

Answer (score 6):

Вот, к примеру, могу вам предложить [анимация](http://www.webmasters.by/creative-css3-animation-menus.html) в меню на CSS3. Вот [демо](http://html5demos.com/) для HTML 5.  Вот тут некоторые [примеры](http://www.tigir.com/javascript.htm) Javascript`а + вот неплохой пример Яваскрипта - [движение текста](http://www.softtime.ru/javascript/movetext.html) по контуру.

Answer (score 5):

[creattica](http://creattica.com/css/latest)

там куча креативщины, проект молодой, но уже свыше 15000 работ. По html5 and css3 почти 3000 работ. Не соскучишься.

Comment: Указанная Вами ссылка в ответе неактивна.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML5 Studio](http://studio.html5rocks.com/) - там ряд примеров на CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

[tympanus](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedOpeningType/). Пощёлкайте по Previous demo. Займёт день, и это будет день открытий чудных.

Comment: действительно круто)

Answer (score 1):

Мои любимые http://www.mrdoob.com/#/131/clouds